# Light box switch wire dilemma

Tags: electrical

I am trying to replace a single pole light switch to a light switch box with one black, green, red, yellow, with orange, white with black tape on the end wires. I’d like to know what is the function of each of these wires and which ones do I use for my single pole 15 amp quiet light switch. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You need to take a few pictures of the junction box before disconnecting any wires. Also show the existing wiring going into the old switch.  The colors of the wires, for the most part, are meaningless because we don't know who did the wiring.

Comment: I would imagine you will connect the new switch the same way as the old switch was connected.  It seems you are using conduit instead cable.  The extra wires might of had a use before or are placed there for future use.  Did you ask a similar question last week?

Comment: White with black tape means it is a hot wire and not neutral.  Green is only to be used for ground, but one question before, show it being used as a hot(probably wrong use).  The other colours of wires are all for hot/live wire use(can have power if connected).

Comment: Is this in North America or Europe?  Cables or individual wires in conduit?  Reason I ask is yellow and orange are quite unusual to find in residential construction in NA, but maybe the previous owner of your house was a plant electrician and used a lot of leftover wire from work?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?